# No ground wire, no box (old or new) trying to install light fixture

Tags: light-fixture, grounding

I just removed an INCREDIBLY old and ugly Hollywood light fixture from my bathroom. The wall now looks like the picture below. I bought a box and a Snap Tite connector. I even got a hold of some grounding screws but then quickly realized (DUH) how am I supposed to ground the actual box? I live in an older home and just wanted to update my lighting fixture. Am I really going to have to call an electrician just to do that?

Please help. I am unsure if I am worrying for nothing or if this is a serious issue.

Thank you all in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You'll need a metal old work box with a BX/AC connector and insulating bushing

Your wiring appears to be BX (old style armored cable).  While the armor on BX is not up to modern standards as a grounding path, it's better than nothing whatsoever, and should be bonded to in any case.  This is done by using an appropriate armored cable connector fitted into a knockout on your new box -- this connector in turn uses a setscrew or spring clamp to retain the cable armor in the connector.

From there, you can ground the light fixture to the box using a grounding pigtail and screw into a 10-32 tapped hole on the back of the box, provided you get the correct box of course.  It will need to be a *metal* box (no plastic here!) with *old work* mounting means that attach to the existing interior sheathing materials (instead of being attached to a stud).

Comment: Three phase eel! Thank you!! This is exactly what I wanted to hear :)

Comment: @MistralKhan-Becerra we say "thank you" around here by upvoting and accepting answers :) (good work with your first question, too -- the clear photo made it an easy win)